# Is this photo showing a woman standing in the nude before teenagers real?

Tags: photography, art

There's a photo going around Twitter and the right-wing blogosphere of a woman standing in the nude at an art exhibition attended by a bunch of teenagers.

I do not want to embed this photo, as it includes nudity..

Here is where I saw it:

[Kane: "Insane Photo — What are they teaching our kids!"
posted on CitizenFreePress on July 28, 2019 12:31 am](https://www.citizenfreepress.com/breaking/insane-photo-what-the-hell-are-they-teaching-our-kids/)
 (archived here: http://archive.is/Yd8pS)

Where is this photo from, and is it real or photoshopped?

Comment: A big hello to the visitors via Hot Network Questions. [Welcome to Skeptics.](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/faq-welcome-to-new-users) Please don't post your opinions or answers in the comments.

Comment: This question has been [discussed on meta](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/should-this-question-have-been-edited-to-provide-positive-spin) and we seem to have resolved the wording.

Comment: Sorry if this was answered in some deleted comments but I’m curious why the crux of your question is around whether the photo is even real, as opposed to the whether the context matches that of the article you linked to (which is the question the accepted answer has really answered). I mean, was it actually claimed anywhere that it’s photoshopped?

Comment: @Darren I thought it was faked because I couldn't believe someone would actually take children to such an exhibit. As an avid reader of right-wing blogs, I'm quite used to fake news there, and I wanted to verify if this was true.

Comment: Ah, so you suspected the blogs had made something up and you were right, just off the mark as to what had been made up.

Comment: @TheAsh In many countries people would think nothing about it, and fifteen year old kids wouldn't need anyone to go anywhere.

Comment: @TheAsh Europeans (especially Nordics) don't get aerated about nudity the way US Americans do.

Comment: @gerrit Children are being taken on a school trip to see a naked woman and you're asking why people would care? I think it is self-evident.

Comment: @gnasher729 As an American, in my culture it's strange. That's why I and many others would care. Perhaps we aren't so "progressive." (The linked article implies it took place in the US, but that's clearly incorrect.)
Either way this whole discussion is irrelevant to the question and asked, and besides, it's already the second time this discussion has happened.

Comment: @TheAsh “self-evident” is cultural, unless there is an inherent biological reason (which is not applicable here). Some cultures frown upon all nudity, some frown upon nudity exposed to children, some cultures don't care. There is a need to be skeptical only if event took place in culture which cares. Personally, I was well into adulthood when I was told that in (for example) the United States, a children's TV program would be unlikely to show nudity (and I still don't know if I was told so correctly, and now makes me wonder if clothing optional beaches in the USA ban children).

Comment: @gerrit "Which is why the culture is relevant to the question and should be edited into it: one would only need to be skeptical to the claim"
No such claim was ever made. The question is simple, is the photo authentic or not? As the OP, I was unfamiliar with those cultures and thought there was a reasonable possibility the picture was faked. The culture it takes place in is irrelevant.

Comment: @TheAsh True, any photo depicting a phenomenon uncontroversial in one culture but controversial in another could be checked for "is it authentic?".  I'm not questioning the clarify of the question, I'm just wondering about the degree of doubtability. What's next? "Are [droppings](https://nltimes.nl/2019/07/22/us-stunned-peculiarly-dutch-rite-dropping) real?", "Do American kids really sing to the flag every morning?", or maybe "Is this picture of children hunting in the mountains real?"

Comment: I've [opened this meta question](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4409/5337) about notability of doubt.

Comment: It almost seems like women are inherently dangerous?! Maybe it's because I'm European, but I don't get it.

Comment: Since the issue is not *"Is the photo real?"* but *"Does the description accurately characterize the photo?" (or misrepresent it)*, the question needs to be restated. (Similar to how the doctored Nancy Pelosi video was "real", although the editing intentionally misrepresented things)

Comment: @smci No it doesn't. that was never the question. The fact that others included it in their answers is beside the point.

Comment: @Dronz "American Christian Conservatives can be extremely misogynistic, homophobic and xenophobic."
I sense projection.

Comment: @Dronz Some Americans also view children as in need of protection from nudity, sexuality, homosexuality, ideas... or they may be "corrupted".
I would argue most, based on the indecentt exposure laws in every state. And yes, I proudly include myself among them.

Comment: @TheAsh: then you're inadvertently misleading all the readers here and multiplying the hoax, by linking to the misleading caption, and you should think more carefully before asking. The actionable question is *""Does the description accurately characterize the photo?" (or misrepresent it)"*. Just because you might be aware the caption was intentionally misrepresenting, other users here wouldnt be. Don't multiply internet hoaxes.

Comment: @TheAsh while at the same time applauding "junior drag queen" contests on MTV...

Comment: @TheAsh I on the other hand remember going to a sauna club with visitors from 6 years to 90 (actually no age limit, but you needed to be able to swim), with the local catholic pastor being a regular customer :-) Dress code: Not dressed :-)

Answer (score 133, accepted):

The photo is real: unstaged and not 'doctored'. But all the surrounding text from the originating claim is misleading.

The photo depicts the artist [Mare](https://www.tralla.net/) [Tralla](http://www.thealit.de/mare_tralla). And some visitors to an art exhibition called [Naine & Naine](https://noar.eu/exhibition-posts/nainenaine/) at the Pärnu Summer festival.

It is important to note that she was scheduled to open [the exhibition](https://linnagalerii.ee/kunstisuvi-esitleb-meesmees-nainenaine/). An exhibition that also showed works by artist [Marko Mäetamm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marko_M%C3%A4etamm) whose works are seen in the pictures.

These are *his* works on the wall and Tralla believes *these* to be sexist. That's why she undressed unexpectedly and began to hang [sheets over Mäetamm's paintings](https://f9.pmo.ee/_kBOLnmqG7erVr2suzlsc0vmQII=/685x410/smart/nginx/o/2019/06/30/12313403t1h2b9b.jpg) with slogan's meant to criticise and expose these sexism depicted on them. As Tralla was only expected to deliver a speech, and not that much more, it was indeed 'a scandal' in Estonia as well. ([Scandal in the Art Hall: Mare Tralla considers the work of a male colleague sexist](https://www.pilguheit.ee/story/197784863/skandaal-kunstisaalis-mare-tralla-peab-meeskolleegi-toid-seksistlikuks))

> Opening the exhibition "Woman and Woman" in Pärnu on Saturday, Mare Tralla caused a scandal with her naked performance: the artist covered the work of Marko Mäetamm, who performed at the exhibition with anti-sex slogans.
>
> However, this is not the only exhibition that explores the boundaries of Pärnu. It could even be said that the summer capital will become the act capital of Estonia. After the 26th nude exhibition "Man, Woman, Freedom" opened in Pärnu City Gallery last Saturday, a man and a man depicting the human body was unveiled, and a bold "Woman and Woman" was set up in the artist house of the city. Tralla's "performance of protest" is now part of the exhibition.
>
> Exhibition “Man, Woman, Freedom” at the Museum of New Art in Pärnu offers a good selection of works by different authors. There are paintings, photos, sculptures, silk paintings, woodcuts and video art outside. In addition, the works of two authors, Kaupo Kikkas' biblically-influenced landscape of human figures and rare photographs of Ernest Hemingway by US painter Waldo Peirce, have been set up in separate halls.
>  <sub>–– [Indrek Tark, Eesti Päevaleht, 1 Juuli 2019](https://epl.delfi.ee/kultuur/konservatiivsed-kehad-ilusad-mehed-ja-poliitilised-naised?id=86702843)</sub>

The so accused artist says to this:

> "I have white skin, I'm a hetero, a team artist too. But in my opinion, my work speaks to women's supremacy," published artist Marko Mäetamm, whose works were criticized by a female artist participating in the grand exhibition Pärnu Art Summer.
>  <sub>–– [Anu Jürisson: "Marko Mäetamm: I stand for my work until I die" – The work of the male artist came under criticism from the female artist, Pärnu Postimees, June 30, 2019.](https://parnu.postimees.ee/6719000/marko-maetamm-seisan-oma-toode-eest-harkisjalu-surmani)</sub>

That means that the headline from CitizenFreePress ("Insane Photo — What the hell are they teaching our kids!") is a incorrect. These are not "our kids" but Estonian visitors to an art exhibition. And this is not about officially "teaching" anything off of the curriculum in school, but an unexpected presence of protest at an art gallery.

The claim-accompanying Twitter post is even worse:

> School kids recently went on a trip to a feminist "art exhibit" and this is what they saw. This is child abuse. This is insanity. This is the lunacy of left wing social engineering in action.

The kids and adults in the picture went to an art exhibition where a male artist displayed his sexually explicit works said to be sexist and abusive of women. A woman protested against this by disrobing. It is difficult to see how this can be accurately described as "the lunacy of left wing social engineering in action".

A better write-up can – at least partially – be found in other English-speaking media, in this case even another right-wing extremists:

- [NewsWars: "WTF? Feminist Strips Naked In Front of Children for Art Display

  European SJW artist claims to be fighting sexist patriarchy"](https://www.newswars.com/wtf-feminist-strips-naked-in-front-of-children-for-art-display/)
- [Caldron Pool: "Feminist, LGBTQ activist strips naked in front of shocked school children to protest sexism"](https://caldronpool.com/feminist-lgbtq-activist-strips-naked-in-front-of-shocked-school-children-to-protest-sexism/)

As one circular reports on this picture:

- [CHILD ABUSE: School Takes Children to Feminist “Art” Exhibit – Kids Get Flashed by Radical Female LGBT Activist (VIDEO)](https://www.thegatewaypundit.com/2019/07/sick-school-takes-children-to-feminist-art-exhibit-kids-get-flashed-by-radical-female-lgbt-activist-video/)

The video in the above link is indeed useful to grasp the atmosphere of the 'performance'.

Regarding 'teaching' and school, it is also relevant that the event took place at the opening of the exhibition. That was a Saturday. 29 June 2019 is also interesting as [12. June 2019 to 31. August 2019 are school summer holidays in Estonia.](https://www.feiertagskalender.ch/ferien.php?geo=3520&hl=en) It may be a bit hasty to infer from that that 'teaching', 'school' and 'this picture' do not have that many connections to a 'school forcing kids', but I'll just go ahead and do that: No school forced any of their teenager students to participate on a Saturday evening during the holidays to go there.

Most people in the picture are adults. For example, the female cap-wearer in front of six female breasts and three vaginas isn't a teenager but art historian [Marian Kivila](https://kultuur.err.ee/309397/mis-toimub-marian-kivila-voib-olla-toesti-mojub-iga-kultuuriline-lisandus-vaikelinna-poolsurnud-peatanaval-anakronistlikult). While she is the [curator of this exhibition](https://maaleht.delfi.ee/news/maaleht/elu/mees-ja-naine-laksid-sulnil-suvisel-kuurordinaitusel-kiskuma?id=86703979), she seems to react in her personal way to [individual exhibits.](https://linnagalerii.ee/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/MMW0098-2-1024x683.jpg)

[image]

[The Pärnu Summer Art festival site describes the intent of the 'exhibition' as:](https://linnagalerii.ee/kunstisuvi-esitleb-meesmees-nainenaine/)

> On June 29, two exhibitions - “Man and Man” and “Woman and Woman” will be opened in Pärnu City Gallery's two exhibition halls. Although the names of the exhibitions may refer to another traditional Pärnu big man and woman's summer exhibition in Pärnu, the exhibitions are not an extension, criticism or parody of the UKM project. Rather, the exhibitions could be seen as an attempt to engage in dialogue with the Pärnu traditions, as well as to dissolve the tradition as a very multi-layered cultural phenomenon and its nature in the sense of body and gender art.
>
> "Man and Man" and "Woman and Woman" bring to the audience the works of Estonian (and one of Russia) artists who, directly or indirectly, dissect the subject of gender roles. And not in the narrow context of erotic art, but in an attempt to open up body and gender reflections in the narrower sense – through everyday humor (Marko Mäetamm), through socio-political-historical prism (Leonhard Lapin, Sandra Jõgeva, Mare Tralla), through contemporary mythology (Andrus Joonas), through the autobiographical spectrum (Rene Kari, Evelin Zolotko), through feminist approaches and the irony of stereotypical gender roles (Lilia Li-Mi-Yan), but also in many other ways.
>
> Participating artists: Mare Tralla, Sandra Jõgeva, Evelin Zolotko (HUUPI), Lilia Li-Mi-Yan, Kiwa, Marko Mäetamm, Rene Kari, Jaanus Samma, Leonhard Lapin, Peeter Allik, Andrus Joonas, Alar Raudoja, Alan Prosa, Anonymous Boh.
>
> Curators of the exhibition are Marian Kivila and Jan Leo Grau (Avangard Gallery, NGO)

For anyone non-Estonian reading along and wondering about cultural differences in attitude towards really *"teaching about sexuality":* in Estonia's schools sexuality-related education starts in grade 5 and the [UNESCO judges](https://www.unaids.org/en/resources/presscentre/featurestories/2011/may/20110506unesco) Estonia's [approach](https://eeagrants.org/News/2017/How-a-website-made-young-Estonians-talk-about-sex) to STDs, pregnancies, etc. as very [effective](https://doi.org/10.1080/14681811.2015.1100599).

Kai Haldre & Kai Part & Evert Ketting: ["Youth sexual health improvement in Estonia, 1990–2009: The role of sexuality education and youth-friendly services"](https://doi.org/10.3109/13625187.2012.696751), The European Journal of Contraception and Reproductive Health Care, October 2012; 17: 351–362

---

Translations from Estonian via Google Translate. Please improve!

Comment: I removed some editorialising. I removed lots of comments both praising and complaining about the levels of editorializing.

Comment: @Oddthinking Hm, why is the para about the obvious target group – more important: the 'feely torsos' – editorialising? As the whole show was about sex & gender but the torsos proof in picture that the claim itself is bigotry & sexism and as such important context.

Comment: I haven't seen confirmation that the 'feely torsos' where being protested against, and I remain agnostic about whether they are bigoted or sexist - that needs a lot more context and art appreciation than I have. What remained appeared to be attacking the Right for attacking the Left, which was getting far away from the original question - are these fake photos?

Comment: @Oddthinking But that's just the point. They *weren't* protested against, as no-one identified them as such in a month old picture/video, even now they raise mostly eyebrows (what's that?), but everyone went ballistic when focussed on the deliberate misinformation they got with captions ("ugly live female forced on our school kids"). That's why the "Photo fake?" also *needs* the tiny frame challenge of "pixels OK, but context pure propaganda, intentionally, and obvious if you take a closer look". Left out context is the wrong half-answer and would just re-inforce the lie.

Comment: It is bigotry to focus "see, unexpected nude Tralla" when there are 3 nice vulvas *meant to be touched.*

Comment: Did I understand correctly that Tralla only protested against a number of paintings on the wall which are not seen in the picture of OP’s claim?

Comment: @Jan I can't say for sure, as the videos of the event I've seen aren't 360° & short. Those pics seen on video to be covered definitively with her sheets and slogans (and thereby obviously made by Mäetamm) appear to have been  mostly in another room.

Answer (score 42):

#### The Short Answer

This is a real photograph of a respected artist in Estonia presenting a creative work to an audience of various ages. The composition of the audience appears to be unremarkable to those present in the photo.

---

#### The Detailed Answer

The image is real in that it does not appear to be substantively altered.  There are no apparent artifacts of a digital recomposition from multiple independently captured or synthesized images, and more compelling there exists a real event from which this image seems likely to have originated.

This image appears to be a photograph of the artist [Mare Tralla](https://www.tralla.net) in an exhibit at [Pärnu City Gallery Artists House](https://linnagalerii.ee/kunstisuvi-esitleb-meesmees-nainenaine/).

So to the question "Is this photo showing a woman posing in the nude before teenagers real?", the answer is almost definitely **yes**.

However, by questioning the veracity of an otherwise unremarkable photo the question suggests that it is uncommon or unreasonable for a woman to be nude in the presence of teenagers, but this cannot be assumed given the photo alone as evidence. Very little if anything can be inferred from the observation that the photo is "real." Certainly nothing along the lines that the linked article claims.

Nudity is reasonable, meaning acceptable to society, in many contexts including and especially art in the United States and other countries. This photo is from Estonia so must be judged in the context of contemporary Estonian culture and whatever specific context surrounded the photo at the time. The evidence on the face of it is that no one in the photo appears to be alarmed at either the nudity or the age of anyone present. Lacking any indication otherwise we must, therefore, conclude that this is acceptable and reasonable in the context to those present, and so is of no particular note. In other words the question draws attention to elements of the image that are immaterial to determining its authenticity.

Mare Tralla appears to be a well-respected artist with a Bachelors of Arts from the Estonian Academy of Arts (1995), and a Masters from the University of Westminster, London (1997). She has curated exhibitions, chaired symposiums, edited books and made many other significant contributions to art and culture. There is even a [Wikipedia article about her](https://et.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mare_Tralla) (in Estonian). She is 52.

Comment: You improved on the first answer. Great job!

Comment: "The evidences on the face of it is that no one in the photo appears to be alarmed at either the nudity or the age of anyone present."
Did you see the kids face?

Comment: @TheAsh Not sure what you mean by that. The kids look like they think she's being silly.

Comment: The conclusion that no-one is visibly objecting in one photo and therefore it is reasonable is [not a safe one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rape#Emotional_and_psychological). I don't think it adds to this answer, and recommend removing it.

Comment: @Oddthinking there was considerable discussion that the editorial context of the photo was not relevant to the question of how real the photos is. While I did not speak to the validity of that assertion I did limit my evaluation to elements that are visible in the image. As part of that evaluation I called into question the relevancy of teenagers in the image as a factor in determining the reality of the photo, because that was a component of the question.

Comment: I did not conclude that "it is reasonable", I concluded that it is irrelevant to the question. The question might as well be "Is this photo real?", because the rest of the question has no impact on the conclusion.

Comment: @TheAsh A) yes the faces are clearly visible, B) "on the face of it" is a phrase meaning "without knowing all of the relevant facts; at first glance," and relates to information not faces.

Comment: @JoshuaKolden I was trying to say the kids looked surprised.

Comment: Because no-one was visible alarmed, you concluded that it was acceptable and reasonable. My link shows that in many clearly unacceptable and unreasonable situations (i.e. rapes), people do not immediately react alarmed, but may freeze or fawn. Therefore your conclusion is unsafe

Comment: @Oddthinking misstating my conclusions does not improve your argument, nor does drawing your own conclusions from an absence of evidence.

Comment: "Nudity is reasonable in many contexts including and especially art even in the United States, "
This is an opinion. Many people would disagree with you. It may be widespread, but it doesn't mean it's reasonable

Comment: Err, perhaps you could reword the second to last paragraph, because I can't see any other way of interpreting it than 'a lack of visible alarm implies it is acceptable'.

Comment: @TheAsh The fact that nudity occurs widely in art even in the US indicates that the majority of people do think it acceptable.

Comment: @Oddthinking how exactly are "clearly unacceptable and unreasonable situations (i.e. rapes)" in any way, shape, or form, related to the photo in question? The photo doesn't portray a _clearly unacceptable or unreasonable situation_ and what the hell are you doing equating this with rape?!

Comment: @AaronF: Please read it again. I did not equate this with rape. I do not care about your opinion on whether this is acceptable or reasonable, just as I am sure you don't care about mine. I do care that there *appears* to be a claim (although it has been refuted) that  a lack of alarm means that it is acceptable and reasonable. I am showing that argument is unsound with a counter example where the same argument fails.

Comment: @DJClayworth No, it merely indicates that there's a vocal minority of artists who think it's acceptable. (Right wing groups protest against it all the time. Don't live in a bubble.)

Comment: @Oddthinking ah. In which case you probably meant "e.g." and not "i.e."! That changes the meaning significantly.

Comment: @Oddthinking, I've edited the paragraph in question for clarity. Hopefully this addresses your concern.

Comment: @TheAsh - Keep in mind that this is Estonia, whose sauna culture is second only perhaps to that of Finland. Non-sexual nudity is not uncommon.

Comment: At one point (in midwestern U.S.), my pre-teen daughter was temporarily scandalized by my quip that "stop and think, everyone _is_ naked under their clothes"... :)

Answer (score 21):

The photo is from an [Estonian exhibition](https://linnagalerii.ee/kunstisuvi-esitleb-meesmees-nainenaine/). The exhibit runs "29.06 – 3.08.2019" or June 29th 2019 through August 3rd 2019. Evidence that this is the correct exhibit is that some of the visitors on the [citizenfreepress](https://www.citizenfreepress.com/column-1/insane-photo-what-the-hell-are-they-teaching-our-kids/) web site image (such as the woman in the pink hat) are also in the exhibit photographs on the linnagalerii web site. I don't believe it is Photoshopped.