# Is The Venice Syndrome documentary cover photo real?

Tags: photography

Came across below photo and eventually tracked it down to a cover photo of "The Venice Syndrome" documentary [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2608566/) and the [trailer at Vimeo](https://vimeo.com/52491214) :

[image: Cover photo.]

This image is not in the trailer (haven't seen the documentary). Big cruise ships do (did) visit Venice as we can see from the trailer, I am not doubting this fact.

**Question:** Is this image real, did this exact cruise ship came to Venice the way it is pictured in the image?

**Update:** Got this image from private chat group claiming it is real. Although no one is claiming it is real in public, it seems relevant to find out if it is photoshopped, i.e.: **added** a big cruise ship just behind the church, for the purpose of exaggerating the effect of the documentary. I understand every cover photo is retouched, as noted in the comments the sky looks like painted.

Comment: Is there a claim this this image is a photograph instead of a painting?

Comment: @FooBar Got it from private chat group claiming it is real, started wondering if it is fake, Google says there are cruise ships, but can't find any reference that this photo is real. Let me know if this post is off-topic on this site (first time poster here, sorry)

Comment: Found [this post](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/44479/34525), and assumed my question might be on topic, too.

Comment: The question is perfectly on topic as long as there is a notable claim that this is in fact a photo. Especially the sky looks painted to me

Comment: Question to mods: do we need [venice](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/search?q=+venice) tag?

Comment: I will point out that the image is "normal" promotional hyperbole, similar to a faked cover on a book.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Thanks, "promotional hyperbole" was the thing I was looking for when I said "exaggerating the effect" :)

Comment: Note that with a very long telephoto lens and shooting from far away, it could be possible to play with the relative size of the boat and the church and make a real picture similar to this cover. Here's an [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective_distortion_(photography)#/media/File:Focal_length.jpg).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No. This particular photo is not real. This particular ship did visit Venice and the photo was taken during that time. Here is a comparison:

[image: Source image of ship and various other photos of it in Venice]

The second photo in this montage shows the source for the cover. You can even see a "pixel" marking on the front from where the lamppost was removed.

[Second proof is this cover for the same movie.](https://www.mfdb.eu/en/film-das_venedig_prinzip_c84292) As you can see the ship is much bigger with same shadow and lights.

Third, the sunlight on the ship is very crisp, shining from the left. The photo of Venice was taken during cloudier day with the sun being behind and on the left of photographer.

Comment: Great! I think 4th image is a different ship.  Thank you, knowing the name of the ship helps a lot with searching "MSC magnifica venice"

Comment: https://goo.gl/maps/JTSGACwsN98qiWXg6 is the dome in the image, photographed from due west. And although you could fit a ship behind the basilica, there are buildings where the photo places the ship.

Comment: Please provide a source for the images.

Comment: also in the cover photo the ship seems to be too high up